# Editing a gridview with AutoGenerateEditButton = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I created a gridview dynamically and added the AutoGenerateEditButton = true; property and i see that it adds the edit link to all the fields when it loads the table into the gridview. But when i click the edit button nothing happens, except for a postback. What am i doing wrong?

```
        GridView gridData = new GridView();
        gridData.ID = "test";
        gridData.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
        gridData.RowEditing += (sender, e) => grid_RowEditing(tbl, e, sender);
        gridData.DataSource = tbl;
        gridData.DataBind();

 protected void grid_RowEditing(DataTable tbl, GridViewEditEventArgs e, object sender)
    {
        ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        // call your databinding method here
        ((GridView)sender).DataSource = tbl ;
        ((GridView)sender).DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that because you are overwriting the grid with every postback by recreating it, the click is just ignored.

The suggested approach would be to create the invisible grid statically:

```
<asp:GridView .... Visible="false" />
```

and then just make it visible when needed. This approach (in contrast to dynamic creation) will save you from dozen of issues, most probably including the one you face.

**Edit:** if you really, really want to follow your route then my guess is that you just haven't specified your data key names so that the edit click carries no information on the clicked row.

```
gridData.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
```

(if your primary key column name is `ID`)

Comment: Your definitely right, and the next time if i get to create this from scratch i will, but now it will be very difficult to do that, because they have a placeholder and create the gridview and then place it in the placeholder

Comment: great idea, but when i add that, it says it cannot convert type string to type string[]

Comment: I'm thinking maybe i can do something like a popup and just edit the gridview from there, any good resources on how to do something like that

Comment: Fixed that. See the answer again.

Comment: I just added that, but i don't know why it just keeps doing a postback

Comment: I just read something, that datatables don't support updates, is there a way to convert it into something that does allow updates

Comment: Yes. Introduce the `ObjectDataSource` as the data source. You can create it programmatically.

Comment: How, do you have an example?

Comment: Not at hand. Google for "create ObjectDataSource programatically". The idea is to have a class with a public method that returns your datatable and another method that accepts modified parameters. Then you create an instance of the ObjectDataSource and set this helper class as its data and bind the grid to the ods. This will work, we have deployed a working solution like 5 years ago with dynamic grids and object data sources bound like that. Come back with specific questions when you encounter further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I added `a <p id="p" runat="server">` on client side and added that grid inside this control.
Here is my code.
I used SqlDataSource instead of Datatable, you can use it any one of it.
Hope it works for u..

```
    protected void gridview()
    {               
        GridView gridData = new GridView();
        gridData.ID = "test";
        gridData.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

        gridData.RowEditing += (sender, e) => grid_RowEditing(SqlDataSource1, e, sender);
        gridData.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        gridData.DataBind();
        p.Controls.Add(gridData);
    }

    protected void grid_RowEditing(SqlDataSource tbl, GridViewEditEventArgs e, object sender)
    {
        ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        // call your databinding method here
        ((GridView)sender).DataSource = tbl;
        ((GridView)sender).DataBind();
    }
```

2) I tried with `datatable` too, and its working.
here is my code.

```
    protected void gridview()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("name");         
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {               
            dt.Rows.Add(i.ToString(),"v"+i.ToString());
        }

        GridView gridData = new GridView();
        gridData.ID = "test";
        gridData.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
        gridData.RowEditing += (sender, e) => grid_RowEditing(dt, e, sender);
        gridData.DataSource = dt;
        gridData.DataBind();
        p.Controls.Add(gridData);
    }

    protected void grid_RowEditing(DataTable tbl, GridViewEditEventArgs e, object sender)
    {
        ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        // call your databinding method here
        ((GridView)sender).DataSource = tbl;
        ((GridView)sender).DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: The `SqlDataSource` is an editable data source. Unfortunately, he is using the `DataTable`. This is why he has to manually handle the `RowEditing` event.